# CSS file is not loaded GAE

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine

I added a CSS file as a static file to my project just to try how it works, but I failed from the beginning.

CSS file is:

```
body {
    background:#00FF00;
}
```

And my configured my app.yaml file is;

```
application: s~my_app_id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /remote_api
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
  login: admin

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: 2.5.1

- name: jinja2
  version: latest

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

It does not work locally or after I deploy it, and my page content in main.py is;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css"/>
       </head>
       <body>
          some stuff
       </body>
   </html>
```

and how my page content in browser is;

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        some stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

I do not get any error or log, everything looks working perfectly. I tried displaying this in chrome and ie10

Comment: If you type in your browser localhost/stylesheets/main.css do you see the contents of you file? or you get a not found? Is your style name main.css or something else? It looks that you are adding a <link> but your browser is rendering <style>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed and readded the project to App Engine SDK and it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to declare it in your app.yaml:

```
application: my-gae-app
version: 2013
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

default_expiration: "14d 5h"

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

If declared like above the CSS will load. You must also load it correctly in your HTML:

`<link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

There is [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles).

Comment: I read this doc before, and it did not help me. As you can see above in my question, it seems like I declared it right. Problem is I am getting no errors but cant display changes. And in the page my CSS file doesnt look attached.